# Apps that include account registration or access a user’s existing account must include a privacy policy or they will be rejected

Tags: iphone

I have submitted the app , Its rejected and that is error.

17.5: Apps that include account registration or access a user’s existing account must include a privacy policy or they will be rejected

I am not getting How to resolve it.How to add privacy policy and how to add URL.If any Tutorial,link Plz tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a privacy policy specific to your application and make it available over the internet.
Use the same url link.

Refer this link: http://www.iubenda.com/en/mobile/

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is a free service with a lot of privacy policy templates [docracy.com/mobileprivacy](http://www.docracy.com/mobileprivacy)